# Is there any way to create a dynamic word document to an existing template in Java?

Tags: java

I need to automatically generate 4 different types of CVs using Java/Spring. The information is already in the database in a structured way. However, we need to generate a Word Document for 4 different types of CVs. If you have noticed in the Europass format there are sections like work-experience and education and training that need to be duplicated more than once.

I have seen a docx4j version , where creating an XML file and adjusting the word document to comply with that XML can make it work. However, what I can't seem to be figuring out for now, is how to add repeating sections, for example a list of experiences. Not only do I have to repeat the actual data, but I also have to duplicate the text in the existing template.

If any of you guys knows any other library/plug-in/tech that might help me to dynamically create a word document (the CV) using Java, please let me know.

Comment: After some research and asking someone I found that ApachePOI is the tool to go. It can create documents in docx and add whatever element we wish for. https://poi.apache.org/components/document/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Apache POI for the given task.